# Google Table Chart export to PDF with autotable

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Hi I am trying to export a Google Table Chart as a PDF. I have tried it this way:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
        doc.text(15, 15, 'Batemo Cell Finder Report');
        // doc.addImage(ScatterChart.getChart().getImageURI(), 15, 40, 180, 160);
        doc.autoTable(document.getElementById("table_div"), 15, 15, {
          'width': 200,
          'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers,
        });
        doc.save('chart.pdf');
```

But it displays the following console error in the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'body' on number '15'
    at parseUserArguments (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:1276)
    at Object.parseInput (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:1195)
    at Object.autoTable (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:1154)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (cell_finder.html:287)
```

How can I get the data displayed. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

the google table chart does produce a normal html `<table>`.
however, it is contained within one or more `<div>` elements.

maybe `autotable` is expecting a table element, rather than a div...

try providing the table element directly...

```
    doc.autoTable(document.querySelector('#table_div table')[0], 15, 15, {
      'width': 200,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers,
    });
```

Comment: it didnt work. It still produces the same error. I tried a different way: 

doc.autoTable({
          head: [[data.getColumnLabel(0),data.getColumnLabel(1),data.getColumnLabel(2),data.getColumnLabel(3),data.getColumnLabel(4)]],
          body: [data.getFilteredRows],
        });

The header works, but I dont know how to get the data for the filtered Rows of the Table.

Comment: following line finally worked:  doc.autoTable({html: document.querySelector('#table_div table')});